# Parameter Null Exception when calling Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

We have been using the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder to create a service provider within a windows service.  We use the service provider to retrieve HttpClient references.  For about 9 months this has been working flawlessly, up until this week when it suddenly throws this exception:

> Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: configureDelegate
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ConfigureServices(Action`2 configureDelegate)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at XYZ.ServiceContainer.CreateHost()
> at XYZ.ServiceContainer.get_Services() ...

The code that is being called:

```
internal static class ServiceContainer
    {
        #region Private Members
        private static object _hostSyncObject = new object();
        private static IHost _serviceHost;
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>Creates the Host</summary>
        private static void CreateHost()
        {
            lock (_hostSyncObject)
            {
                if (_serviceHost == null)
                {
                    HostBuilder hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();
                    hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureHostService);
                    _serviceHost = hostBuilder.Build();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configures the given service container
        /// </summary>
        private static void ConfigureHostService(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>Services</summary>
        internal static IServiceProvider Services
        {
            get
            {
                if (_serviceHost == null)
                {
                    CreateHost();
                }
                return _serviceHost?.Services;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And the code that calls the Services property above:

```
IHttpClientFactory factory = (IHttpClientFactory)ServiceContainer.Services.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
HttpClient client = factory.CreateClient();
```

We are using version 5.0 of the Microsoft Extension assemblies and .NET Framework v4.8.  The weird thing is according to the stack trace the Build() method should be calling ConfigureServices(...) but I actually do not see this in the source code for [this class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostBuilder.cs) online.

Frustratingly, I do not see the error when I try to run it locally.  The servers where the code is failing were verified to have the correct code installed (thought it may be a version issue with the Extension assemblies).  I am at a loss on what could cause this to start failing out of the blue.

Does anyone have an idea on why this is failing?  I just don't understand why this would work for so long and then just quit.

Answer (score 2):

For those that had the issue, it appears our issue was caused by a bug introduced with a new version of Dynatrace.  They had pushed a fix out Sunday night which is why for most of us it had appeared to fix itself by Monday morning.  We did have to restart services in some environments before they started working again.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue on 14 July 2023. We have a Cronjob deployed to Azure Kubernetes. When the job was triggered as scheduled, this error happened.
Exception when creating Host builder. Our Cronjob was working before that date.

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configureDelegate')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ConfigureServices(Action`2 configureDelegate)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
```

Our CreateHostBuilder method:

```
  static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddLogging();
            //...
        });
```

This error happens in all our Env such as UAT, and Staging.
Fortunately, the Cronjob is working today, 17/7/2023.

I have not found out the root cause yet.
Code version: .Net Core 3.1.
Azure Kubernetes version: 1.26.3

Comment: Well, it looks like it cleared up on one of our environments but our production environment is still failing.  There were no code pushes to the one that now works either.  I just sort of 'fixed itself'.  I am really confused by this, and also the fact that the stack trace doesn't match the source code that MS has.

Comment: We also had the same issue. Started happening around the same time (early last week), and magically fixed itself this morning when we restarted our kubernetes pods. No code changes. We use docker (using `dotnet/sdk:6.0` for build and `dotnet/aspnet:6.0` for runtime).